# Read error: ssl=0xc2befd00: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

Used platforms:
Ionic mobile application with IBM MFP8.0 Server.

Configuration:
Mobile Application communicates to the server with public domain via HTTPS protocol. Request flow is passed from Internet to intranet & SSL offloading is done at RP and passed to LB. LB in-front of MFP server.

Problem Statement:
When the Application launched and closed continuously or when i refresh the application the below error occurs,

> -- failure: {"status":-1,"responseText":"","responseHeaders":{},"errorMsg":"Read
>   error: ssl=0xc2befd00: I/O error during system call, Connection reset
>   by peer","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR"}

The issue occurrence is intermittent

What I did:
There is SSL pinning code integrated with the Application

> WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey('myCertificate.cer').then(onSuccess,
>   onFailure);

I tried commenting this piece of code as well never helped.

Any recommendation to fix this issue.

Comment: When i try to call the MFP adapters from mobile application this error pops-up,This is shown only on client side logs. From server logs i dint find the request reaching my server.

Comment: Is this specific to older Android devices? Or do you see this problem with all devices and iOS devices too?

Comment: yes, Its happening for both the devices Ios & android